# jQuery UI effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I show a `div` growing from top and bottom with jqueryui effect?

I tried this code:

```
$('div#my').show('clip');
```

but it does not work.

Comment: this is not enough to solve the problem, if possible then pls make an http://jsfiddle.net/ and show that fiddle link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does slideUp or slideDown help you?

```
$('div#my').slideUp('slow');
$('div#my').slideDown('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use animation without jQuery UI using `.show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )`.

The code for this would be `$('div#my').show('slow');`

For using custom effects such as `clip`, I would think your code would work as expected, but if not maybe your path to your jquery UI is off?

Here is a demo of your code working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/ysHgp/

Answer (score 0):

An other way is $('div#my').animate({ height: heightOfDiv_my }, "fast");